# Java: offer a filtered view on a class

Tags: java, oop, object

I have a class with a large amount of data, and I would like to expose a "filtered view" on this object with the same methods, but a modified output.
To give a very basic example, let's say that I have such a class:

```
public class Booleans {
    private boolean[] data;

    public Booleans(boolean[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean getDataAt(int i) {
        return data[i];
    }

    public Booleans opposite() {
        // What to return here? b.opposite().getDataAt(i) should be !b.getDataAt(i)
    }
}
```

Is there a good pattern to write the opposite method? I need to be as memory efficient as possible: the data can not be duplicated, and a call to "opposite" should ideally not create any object, as it will be called many times.

Creating one small object in the constructor of Booleans would be fine for example, but I can not refer "this" at that point...

Comment: If `opposite` cannot create any object, that means that it must mutate the current instance, yes? As in, `opposite()` must return `this`?

Comment: I can not have opposite modify the original object, it has to be just a different "view" on the same data.

Comment: If you can't modify the object, and you can't create a new object... there are no other options, really. The only other thing is to have a `boolean` outside your `Booleans` instance, and explicitly call `bool ^ booleans.getDataAt(i)` each time.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify this - I would be fine with having a small constant overhead in memory, but I can't really create objects every time "opposite" is called as in Mshnik's answer

Comment: Unless this is for hw, then I believe you're micro-optimizing a bit too much. It's very unlikely, with sane-ish code, you'd be able to generate enough objects fast enough to out-pace the GC, and therefore the requirement of "not creating any objects" is unlikely to have any noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: You are probably correct in general, however my code will not be executed in a standard JVM, and I need to write code as efficient as possible regarding the memory usage and throughput...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get away with no object creation. You can however get away with a very cheap object creation:

```
private transient Booleans opposite;

static class BooleansOpposite extends Booleans {
     Booleans original;

     BooleansOpposite(Booleans original) {
         super(null);
         this.original = original;
     }

     public Booleans opposite() {
         return original;
     }

     public boolean getDataAt(int i) {
          return !original.getDataAt(i);
     }
}

public Booleans opposite() {
    if (opposite == null) {
        opposite = new BooleansOpposite(this);
    }
    return opposite;
}
```

This basically uses the Decorator pattern to alter the behavior of the getDataAt method. Although the first call of opposite creates an object, the only cost you pay is the one for BooleansOpposite that holds no data, since it refers back to its parent. You could also create the opposite instance ahead of time in the constructor if you prefer eager initialization.

It would work even better if Booleans were just an interface or a pure abstract class that does not define any members, then the BooleansOpposite implementation would not need to inherit useless fields.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed - and your comment about having an interface makes perfect sense, I should have thought of it!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to provide a way to keep the interface of your class the same, but the implementation should be different (in this case opposite) as far as some methods are concerned. It is not clear what kind of constraints you have, other than the apparent fact that you don't want to be creating too many objects.

I am suggesting a solution that may be initially frowned upon, but may actually help in case you have many such methods some of which should just *pass through*, others not so. This is called the dynamic proxy pattern. Its implementation is somewhat slower than the more straightforward approach, but it may fit your needs. I fear that the complexity is slightly more than what you may want, but I thought it is better to have options from which you can choose.

I suggest that you extract the interface out first:

```
interface BooleanArray {
    /** Returns the boolean at given index */
    boolean getDataAt(int i);
    /** Returns a BooleanArray implementation that is "opposite" */
    BooleanArray opposite();
}
```

Then provide one concrete implementation: `Booleans`. Now, for the `opposite()` method, we are going to piggyback on the existing target implementation and then complement the results.

Below is complete (working) code that demonstrates the idea.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

/** Proxy-based attempt to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805928/java-offer-a-filtered-view-on-a-class
 */
interface BooleanArray {
    boolean getDataAt(int i);
    BooleanArray opposite();
}
public class Booleans implements BooleanArray {
    private final boolean[] data;
    private volatile BooleanArray OPPOSITE;

    public Booleans (boolean[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private Object initOpposite(BooleanArray target) {
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(Booleans.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{BooleanArray.class},
                new ComplementHandler(target));
    }

    public boolean getDataAt(int i) {
        return data[i];
    }

    public BooleanArray opposite() {
        if (OPPOSITE == null)
            OPPOSITE = (BooleanArray) initOpposite(this);
        return OPPOSITE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanArray ab = new Booleans(new boolean[]{true, false, true});
        BooleanArray ba = ab.opposite();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
            System.out.println(ab.getDataAt(i) + " and: " + ba.getDataAt(i));
    }
    private static final class ComplementHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        private final BooleanArray target;
        public ComplementHandler(BooleanArray target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if ("getDataAt".equals(method.getName())) {
                Boolean orig = (Boolean) method.invoke(target, args);
                if (orig)
                    return Boolean.FALSE;
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
            return method.invoke(target, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach... I do have quite a few methods in my actual use-case class/interface, so this might be interesting, but I'm a bit concerned by the cost of using reflection.
I will use Durandal's pattern for now, but I can see how if the class grows with more methods your approach might be better to avoid code rewrite...
I will upvote your answer as soon as I have enough reputation, as I think it is good ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably return an `Iterator` and program the iterator to skip the value you're concerned about. O(# of skipped items) memory which I think is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

That method should return a new Object Booleans but** all the elements of that array are just the negation or complement of the actual instance.

example:

Comment: you missed the example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without creating a single object (you do have to return something that isn't `this`), but you can do it without recreating data. (Hence O(1) space).

One solution is to create a new instance that doesn't store any data (thus no need to copy the data), but have it always return the opposite of this' data.

```
  public Booleans opposite() {
    return new Booleans(){
      @Override
      public boolean getDataAt(int i) {
        return !vals[i];
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: This would create one new object everytime "opposite" is called, I would like to avoid that (I edited my question to make it clearer)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is memory efficiency, why not use a BitSet instead of an array?

Each element in a boolean[] array takes 1 byte of memory while each boolean in a BitSet takes 1 bit of memory rounded to the next byte.

Also, i would just create a second oppositeBitSet, and whenever you modify the originalBitSet with value, just modify oppositeBitSet with !value.

And, the bitset has

void          flip(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
Sets each bit from the specified fromIndex (inclusive) to the specified toIndex (exclusive) to the complement of its current value.

**I just started studying collections, so let me know if something here is incorrect or why bitSets are not advisable.

Comment: The example was just the simplest class that I could come up with to illustrate my problem, in reality it is not a boolean array. You are correct that such an array wouldn't be optimal.